# Matplotlib: plt.xtick bug when used with sns.FacetGrid

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to do something relatively simple with sns.FacetGrid (see code below). For N = 10, k = 10 and scale = 1 the plots look fine (except for `bins = np.arange(k+1) - 0.5` *not* setting labels in the middle of each column), but as you increase k, the *last* figure in the plot goes awry and adapts k xticks.

k = 10

[image]

k = 30

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from ipywidgets import interact

%matplotlib inline

def stateplot(N,k,scale):

    sns.set(style="ticks")

    rs = np.random.RandomState(4)
    value = np.round(rs.exponential(scale, (N,k)),0)
    macrostate = np.repeat(range(N), k)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[value.flat,macrostate],columns=["value","state"])
    grid = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="state", hue="state", col_wrap=5, 
                         size=2,legend_out=False,xlim=(0,8))
    bins = np.arange(k+1) - 0.5
    grid.map(plt.hist, "value", bins=bins, 
             lw=0,align='left').set_axis_labels(" ", " ").set_titles(" ")
    labels = [' ',r'$0{\Delta}$',r'$1{\Delta}$',r'$2{\Delta}$',r'$3{\Delta}$'
              ,r'$4{\Delta}$',r'$5{\Delta}$',r'$6{\Delta}$',r'$7{\Delta}$']
    plt.xticks(list(range(k)), labels)
```

I'm thinking it's bug - or that I'm using plt.xticks wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The priblem with using `plt.xticks` is that it should only act on the last subplot active (in this case, the bottom right). [Note, it seems to set the xticklabels on all subplots, but not the ticks]

There are a couple of ways you can set the `xticklabels` for all subplots. Probably the best way would be to use the `set_xticklabels` method of the `FacetGrid` object. So, you could do this:

```
def stateplot(N,k,scale):

    sns.set(style="ticks")

    rs = np.random.RandomState(4)
    value = np.round(rs.exponential(scale, (N,k)),0)
    macrostate = np.repeat(range(N), k)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[value.flat,macrostate],columns=["value","state"])
    grid = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="state", hue="state", col_wrap=5, 
                         size=2,legend_out=False,xlim=(0,8))
    bins = np.arange(k+1) - 0.5
    grid.map(plt.hist, "value", bins=bins, 
             lw=0,align='left').set_axis_labels(" ", " ").set_titles(" ")

    labels = [' ',r'$0{\Delta}$',r'$1{\Delta}$',r'$2{\Delta}$',r'$3{\Delta}$'
              ,r'$4{\Delta}$',r'$5{\Delta}$',r'$6{\Delta}$',r'$7{\Delta}$']
    grid.set_xticklabels(labels)
```

An alternative way of doing this is to use the option `subplot_kws` to `FacetGrid`, and set the `xticklabels` that way. You need to define `labels` before `FacetGrid` for that to work:

```
def stateplot(N,k,scale):

    sns.set(style="ticks")

    rs = np.random.RandomState(4)
    value = np.round(rs.exponential(scale, (N,k)),0)
    macrostate = np.repeat(range(N), k)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[value.flat,macrostate],columns=["value","state"])
    labels = [' ',r'$0{\Delta}$',r'$1{\Delta}$',r'$2{\Delta}$',r'$3{\Delta}$'
              ,r'$4{\Delta}$',r'$5{\Delta}$',r'$6{\Delta}$',r'$7{\Delta}$']
    grid = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="state", hue="state", col_wrap=5, 
                         size=2,legend_out=False,xlim=(0,8),subplot_kws={'xticklabels':labels})
    bins = np.arange(k+1) - 0.5
    grid.map(plt.hist, "value", bins=bins, 
             lw=0,align='left').set_axis_labels(" ", " ").set_titles(" ")
```

Comment: Actually `xticks()` is changing the ticks in the last subplot (as I woud expect) and the labels in **all** subplots in the lower row (which I wouldn't expect at all). It might be just how FacetGrid works but I find it weird.

Comment: The "more seaborn friendly way" to do this is to use the `set` method on the `FacetGrid` object.

Comment: @mwaskom thanks, that is more friendly! I'll edit the answer.